# What can cause prediction delay in decision tree-based regressions?

Tags: regression, random-forest, boosting, cart

I am experiencing *a delay* between the test data and predictions after some time:

[image]

The first row **is earlier** than the second row. Data are residuals calculated on time series velocity data.

Why does such a delay occur? How can I investigate this further?

Edit: To clarify, in the first row that corresponds to the first 50k points, there is no delay, in the second row that corresponds to the last 50k points, there is a delay. So delay occurs after some time.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what youdo but this seems like the output of an AR model right? XGBoost doesn't seem to do anything wrong, the fit "bad" and XGBoost recreates it.

Comment: These are the outputs of regressors, you can see the type from the legend. There is a delay in all of them.

Comment: That's why it is good to show the X-axis...